# Estimating number of maximum threads before bus contention

Tags: multithreading, bus, contention

Suppose I have an arbitrary number of threads that need to read from different memory locations. What parameters do I need to estimate the maximum number of threads that can do this simultaneously without bus contention? Where can this information be found for commercially available hardware?

Comment: That depends too much on cache design, sizes, configuration, OS memory management and the locations addressed to be answerable on SO.

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb or average for commercial hardware?

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: Is there a way to measure when contention occurs? If I start with 1 thread and progressively increase the number of threads, is there a way to know?

Comment: I don't know.  Bus contention has not surfaced as a performance constraint on any app that I have developed, so I have not researched it.  I don't use multiple threads to specifically improve data processing throughput - I use them to logically seperate blocks of asynchronous functionality.